# Use country-specific google in searchbar?

Tags: firefox, google-search

In firefox you can enter your search terms in the URL bar, and it will start a search in the engine you defined. If you choose `google` in the preferences, it will use `google.com`. This has the backdraw that you cannot restrict the search to your own country.

> How can I use e.g. `google.fr` or `google.it` instead?

In earlier versions you could specify the URL of the search engine you wanted to use, but it appears that now you can only choose from a predefined list:

[image]

I think I have read somewhere that you can tweak some settings in `about:config`, but I was unable to find those.

EDIT: The person asking [here](https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/990654) seemed to have the same problem. Aparently `keyword.URL` was removed a while back. But that only `google.com` is available must have changed more recently, as I do use the country restriction very frequently.

Comment: I believe that Google themselves really no longer support using "foreign" sites; if it detects that your IP is within a national block, it seems to redirect all searches to that national site.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin When you use any of the local sites (`.fr`, `.it` etc) you can still restrict the search to the country you're accessing the side from (but not necessarily the one the domain ending indicates), while this option is *not* available using `.com`.

Comment: See this link https://www.rankranger.com/blog/how-to-track-google-international-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using the search engine plugins collected by the mycroft project:

http://mycroftproject.com/google-search-plugins.html

Answer (score 1):

## Add Custom Search Engine in Firefox (Desktop)

> Current Firefox version is 108.0 at the time of writing.

For some incomprehensible reason, the button to add additional search engines is hidden by default:

It should show down here:
[image: No add button]

You can fairly simply bring this add option back so you can set your search default to your localised Google page like `.fr` or `.it` (without unnecessary plugins).

1. Put the add button back by going to `about:config`:

   [image: go to about:config]
2. Create a new preference named `browser.urlbar.update2.engineAliasRefresh` as a boolean value:

   [image: Add new preference]
3. Make sure it is set as `true`:

   [image: Make sure it's true]
4. Add should now be back again:

   [image: Add is back; back again]
   (Refresh the page if it doesn't show)
5. Click add, put whatever name you like and then put the appropriate engine URL:

   [image: Put in the values]

   For this example I am putting in Google Australia with the search url being `https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%s`. You can change the `.au` with whatever country you are after. The alias is optional.
6. You will now see your new search engine as an option in the Default Search Engine dropdown:

   [image: Default it]
7. Searches will now use this by default:

[image: Success]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a ton for this! This worked perfectly!

I actually went one step further and set my Search Region as well: Bottom-Right Corner of "www.google.com" "Settings->Search Settings" "Search results->Region Settings"...as well as added the country's language in that same menu but in "Languages->Results language filter"

Now I can freely switch between the 2 search engines as my default url bar search engine...thanks!

Comment: Google don't use country domains since 2017 to serve search results.

Comment: @Wicket Behold! The magic of google.com.au vs google.com: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdKNX.png). The filtering option only shows on google.com.au version and is useful when trying to filter out results from the juggernaut that is the US. Especially useful when finding local suppliers of small US brands. The US results can block out the sun otherwise.

Comment: The answer should be updated (fixed). P.S. If I use google.com.au, the country dropdown only shows two options: Any country and my country. Remember that you can use Advanced Search, google.com/advanced_search to access all the filters. It will not show dropdowns for all used filters on the results page, so you might want to highlight the country filter dropdown in your answer as a unique feature of the country domain.

Comment: @Wicket in the end the question is "[How can I] Use country-specific google in searchbar?", which is what's answered. The advanced search is neat though, I've never noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Instead of using a hack, follow the instructions from the official docs: [Make Google your default search engine](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/464?hl=en), use the Google Search settings to set your preferences.

---

Most users don't care about the base URL on the address bar. Most are looking to control the scope of the results returned by Google; however, to understand the above, please note that in October 2017 on [Making search results more local and relevant](https://blog.google/products/search/making-search-results-more-local-and-relevant/), Google announced that they stopped redirecting users to country top-level domains. Hence, using [www.google.com/ncr](http://www.google.com/ncr) is no longer necessary to keep showing [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) on the web browser address bar. Also, using top-level country domains like google.fr and google.it is not giving the same benefits that used to be. They might still be working for backward compatibility but might not get the same attention as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), i.e., to fix bugs, etc.

Now, instead of using the country's top-level domain to customize the results for the user, Google takes the location by other means, like the location based on the public IP address, the geolocation data if the web browser and the device are allowed to send this data or a query string parameter that could be set by using Advanced Search or a manually crafted URL.

Regarding how Google uses the user location, read [Understand & manage your location when you search on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/179386?hl=en).

Now, Google's results page includes tools that vary depending on the query. Check out [Learn search tips & how results relate to your search on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/10563935?hl=en).

Below, I'm quoting the section corresponding to the Country (links not included).

> ##### Country/Region and Language
>
> Usually, helpful results match your language and region in the Search settings. However, sometimes Search might identify helpful results in other languages or from other regions. Here are a couple examples:
>
> - If your language is set to English but you search in Chinese, the most relevant results might be written in Chinese.
> - If you’re in the US and you search for india news, the most relevant results might be content from India.
>   The “Your search & this result” section highlights the language and region of a result:
> - This result is in .
> - This result seems relevant, even though it’s not in .
> - This result seems relevant for searches from .
> - This result seems relevant for searches from many regions, including .
> - This result seems relevant for this search, even though it typically appears for searches outside .
>
> Tip: To find results in other languages, try Advanced Search. You can also change your language and region in your Search settings. Learn how to change your language and find results for a different country.

Comment: How else would you duplicate [this filter result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdKNX.png)? The US store has expensive shipping, so I want only local results. By default Google gives me the US store as #1, even though my location is set to Australia, along with all my Google settings across all my devices. The amazon link is more relevant for my needs. Are you able to make it the number 1 result without using filters?

Currently the `.au` domain filter is the simplest option I have found, hence why setting it as the default search provider in the browser is still useful. Is this false?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.google.it/ncr or https://www.google.fr/ncr
Add any of these two links inside the Search Engine list.
Good luck :)

Comment: I do know the urls I want to use, I just don't know how to add those, which was what I was asking.

Comment: Ohh sorry. I thought you we're asking how to use another Google country without redirecting you to .com one.